# C# Serial Port Opening Produces Odd Output Behavior from Device

Tags: c#, serial-port, monitoring

I am working on a project that uses a [RAZOR D9OF](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10736) (Accelerometer, Magnetometer, and Gyroscope) I am making a simple C# form which opens the serial port that the RAZOR is on (in my case it's Port 4, @ 57600 baud rate) and lists all output from the guy.

Using Arduino's Serial Monitor, I see that the device outputs the following:

```
ITG: GOOD
HMC: GOOD
ADXL: GOOD

9DOF IMU Firmware v23 
==========================
[1]Accelerometer: ADXL345 
[2]Magnetometer: HMC5883 
[3]Gyroscope: ITG-3200 
[4]Raw Output
[5]Change Baud Rate: 57600bps
[Ctrl+z]Toggle Autorun
[?]Help
```

What's interesting to note is that every time I close the Serial Monitor, and **reopen** it, I am greeted to the same exact output from the device.

Now, when using my C# form, I open the port as follows:

```
using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 57600))
{
    port.Open();

    string inp = port.ReadLine();

    while (!inp.Contains("Help")) // Looking for the '[?]Help' delimiter
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inp);
        inp = port.ReadLine();
    }

    //At this point the device is ready for input, send commands, and when done,

    port.Close();
}
```

The first time the form runs, I get the same output as I expect:

```
ITG: GOOD
HMC: GOOD
ADXL: GOOD

9DOF IMU Firmware v23 
==========================
[1]Accelerometer: ADXL345 
[2]Magnetometer: HMC5883 
[3]Gyroscope: ITG-3200 
[4]Raw Output
[5]Change Baud Rate: 57600bps
[Ctrl+z]Toggle Autorun
```

However, whenever I run this code again, in the same form session, the resulting output is as follows:

1. '/r/r'
2. nothing, the read command hangs

Even when I close the form, and restart the form in debugging mode, the very first output is one of the two above. The only time the device resets back to the normal output (like that of the Arduino Serial Monitor) is **when I power off the device and power it back on, switch USB ports, or press the onboard reset button**.

I then tried using EventHandlers, like so:

```
... in PortOpen() ...
    _RAZOR_ = new SerialPort(cbCOMs.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), getBaudRate());
    _RAZOR_.Open();
    _RAZOR_.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_RAZOR_dataRecieved);

    private void _RAZOR_dataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string telemetry = "";
        try { telemetry = _RAZOR_.ReadLine().ToString(); }
        catch { return; }

        Console.WriteLine(telemetry);
    }

... in CloseRAZORPort() ...
        _RAZOR_.Close();
        _RAZOR_.Dispose();
```

and get the same behavior as before.

[I read that there may be a bug with .NET's implementation of SerialPort](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce8ce1a3-64ed-4f26-b9ad-e2ff1d3be0a5/serial-port-hangs-whilst-closing?forum=Vsexpressvcs) but I am not sure if my situation is similar to that or not...

There is something Arduino's Serial Monitor is doing to reset or reload the device that I am not doing, I believe, and that is what is causing the weird behavior of the output.

Does anyone have any suggestions or notes to give on what I can do to alleviate this? Every time I open the port to the device, I *need* to have the device status that it prints in the beginning.

Comment: From their Git, (https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/c70efd950f588973f5ebcd45590e9bcb45791db4/app/src/processing/app/SerialMonitor.java) is their Serial object overridden with this FTDI chip you speak of?

Comment: I think the Arduino auto resets when you reopen the serial monitor. So that would compare to "restart your C# app". If you restart your C# app, you do get similar results, right? Could it be that your buffers still contain data when you reopen the port? (Maybe you could try `port.DiscardInBuffer()` and `port.DiscardOutBuffer()` before you open it, or after you close it)

Comment: @bas, just tried, works the first time, just like before, but now hangs on the first read line.